# Diversity in Anatomical model?

Tags: graphics3d, anatomy

I was looking at Mathematica anatomical models and was able to generate images like that

```
AnatomyPlot3D[{Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "SkinOfNeck"], 
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Ear"], 
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "SkinOfHead"], 
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "HairOfHead"]}]
```

[image: Head image]

What about female, non-blonde and non-white head models?

Comment: You should ask Wolfram about adding this data. I don't think it would be appropriate for anyone here to tweak the existing data to fake it.

Comment: While I absolutely agree with @flinty (especially because even well-intentioned tweaks could not go over well), having the issue raised and left longer for more folks to see it is essential.  I ask that the final close vote be held off for a while.

Comment: Can you suggest another public Mathematica forum where this should be posted to obtain a response from a company representative?